# Past or Present tense

Tags: grammar

After inviting someone attend an event, is it grammatically correct to say, " Your presence was much appreciated," or "Your presence is much appreciated."

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the timing.

If the person has accepted your invitation, or it's assumed the person will attend after being invited, you could say "Your presence is much appreciated".  (This is most correct if the event is currently occurring, but it's quite common in English to refer in this way, even if the attendance will be in the future.)

On the other hand, if the event has already happened and is over, or the event is still happening but the person did attend and has now left, saying "Your presence was much appreciated" would be perfectly appropriate.